# Flipping horizontally sprites slick2d

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm writing an arcade multi-level game with Slick2D and I'm writing the code of the entities. I'm trying to flip horizontally the sprite. The first time I designed 2 images for the same sprite, the first facing right and the second facing left.

Now I'm trying to flip horizontally the sprite with the `getFlippedCopy()` function, but I cannot rotate the entire animation, I can rotate only a frame.

How can I solve?

Comment: Can you post the code where you're doing the rotation and image initialization and your render method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing an animation, it can be best to utilize the getCurrentFrame() method, as that's what's about to be displayed anyway.

Do something like this:

```
animation.getCurrentFrame().getFlippedCopy(direction, false).draw(x, y);
```

With this in your render method, you set the orientation of the image based on the direction they are face. So if they are facing left, 'direction' could be true, so the current animation image will draw flipped at that x and y (which is what you want), and if facing right, direction would be false, in which no flipped orientation would occur and it would show the player facing right (depending on the image; if they are facing left in the original spritesheet, the opposite will be true).

If you are doing a bit more complex orientation changes, such as 4 directional movement:

```
anim.getCurrentFrame().setRotation(90*(direction));
anim.getCurrentFrame().draw(x, y);
```

where 'direction' is a North/East/South/West representative integer, 0-3. Such as 0 = North, 1 = East, etc etc.

Comment: The first code is perfect cause the player will walk facing only left/right, but if I apply the code the sprite animation stop :\

Comment: I solved, I had only to write 'animation.update(delta)' in my update method :) Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes, I would've mentioned that, but I wasn't sure what your code looked like for your render method. Glad it helped, though!

Animations are very handy in slick, and they can do a surprising amount of things, since you can get the frame being referenced to be drawn. You can manipulate it in any way a regular image can be manipulated :)